# How to get status of executing build steps in teamcity?

Tags: rest, build, teamcity

I used the below API call to get the list of steps available for a particular build configuration, how do I check the status of steps completed on running builds?

```
http://localhost:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/GreenHouse_Sit/steps
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems most you can get is a percentage of completeness and current stage text. The latter one is interesting here, as it starts with `Step X/Y` string (when executing Xth step) so you can easily process it:

```
http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:BUILD_TYPE_ID,state:running&fields=build(running-info(currentStageText,percentageComplete))`
```